# Python 2.7 sort list

Tags: python

How can I sort this list that everything without start with "something" found on top of the list?

```
a = ['something7375', 'something6375', 'something37573', 'something93746',\
     'Whatever22', 'whatever74', 'other837', 'other8394']

print sorted(a, key = lambda s: s.lower())
```

The result is

```
['other837', 'other8394', 'something37573', 'something6375',\
 'something7375', 'something93746', 'Whatever22', 'whatever74']
```

and I would like to be:

```
['other837', 'other8394', 'Whatever22', 'whatever74',\
 'something37573', 'something6375', 'something7375', 'something93746']
```

Comment: You want it sorted by string length?

Comment: You could probably do this using some slightly complicated key function but it's probably more intuitive to just split it into two lists, sort each, then rejoin.

Comment: He wants it sorted such that words that start with something are sorted on their own, apart from other words, and at the end of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that tuples/lists will sort first by the first element, then second, etc. Create a key function that returns a tuple starting with 1 for anything that starts with "something", and 0 otherwise.

```
def somethingkey(k):
    k = k.lower()
    if k.startswith('something'):
        return (1, k)
    else:
        return (0, k)

a = ['something7375', 'something6375', 'something37573', 'something93746', 'Whatever22', 'whatever74', 'other837', 'other8394']

>>> print sorted(a, key=somethingkey)
['other837', 'other8394', 'Whatever22', 'whatever74', 'something37573', 'something6375', 'something7375', 'something93746']
```

Comment: you can even reduce this to one line `print sorted(a, key = lambda x: (x.startswith('something'),x.lower()))` why? because python rocks

Answer (score 0):

```
print sorted(a, key = lambda s: s.lower() if s.lower().startswith('something') else 'z'+s.lower())
```

this is assuming that all your list items start with letters but it should work

```
>>> a = ['something7375', 'something6375', 'something37573', 'something93746',     'Whatever22', 'whatever74', 'other837', 'other8394']
>>> print (sorted(a, key = lambda s: s.lower() if s.lower().startswith('something') else 'z'+s.lower()))
['other837', 'other8394', 'Whatever22', 'whatever74', 'something37573', 'something6375', 'something7375', 'something93746']
```

Comment: `not in` isn't appropriate here; an item might contain `something` but not *start* with `something`.

Comment: i had assumed that it was just looking for any instance of something in the string so yeah youre correct. editted to use `.startswith()`